# How to determine if a function is a linear functional.

Tags: linear-algebra

We are studying linear functionals and many of the examples just state that something is a linear functional with no explanation as to why... I know that with most of the linear algebra concepts there are specific properties that must be satisfied but I do not see any for linear functionals.

Can anyone explain to me how to determine if a function is a linear functional?

For example:

Let $V=C(0,1)$. From calculus we know that for each $f\in V$ there exists a maximal element $a_f$ of $\{f(t)|0 \le t \le 1\}$ . Is the function $f\mapsto a_f$ a linear functional on $V$?

Comment: This seems quite easy to just google. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFunctional.html). Is there something you need to have clarified from this page?

Comment: Ah yes, I did see that page and what is there makes sense. I guess my question needs to be more specific. I will edit to add an example of what I am looking at.

Comment: No, it's not linear. Look at my answer to figure out which property fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your example, i.e. $V = C([0,1])$, and the functional $f\mapsto \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x)\}$. To be precise, the functional which we may call $L$, is a function $L:V\to \mathbb{R}$ and is defined by
$$Lf = \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x)\}.$$

Consider the functions $f,g\in V$ defined by $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = -x$. Note that they actually are members of $V$ as long as we restrict their domain to $[0,1]$.

Then 
$$L(f+g) = \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x) + g(x)\} = \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{0\} = 0, $$
however
$$L(f) + L(g) = \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x)\} + \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{g(x)\} = \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{x\} + \max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\{-x\} = 1+0 = 1.$$
Since $L(f+g) \neq L(f)+L(g)$ the functional is not additive, and hence not linear.

Comment: In this instance I can see where using x and -x is a good choice. However, I do not understand choosing f and g for some other problems. For example: how to chose f and g for a function $p(x) \mapsto p(a)-p(0)$ where $a \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a linear operator is that it has two properties:

1. distributive across addition: $\mathcal{L}[f + g] = \mathcal{L}[f] + \mathcal{L}[g],$ for any functions $f$ and $g$;
2. commutes with multiplication: $\mathcal{L}[a \cdot f] = a \cdot \mathcal{L}[f],$ for any function $f$ and any scalar $a$.

You can replace 'function' in the above with 'vector', since this definition applies to any vector space, which function space is an example of, and the vector space is what supplies the definitions of scalar multiplication and addition.

Comment: One more thing: the co-domain of a linear functional is (a subset of) the scalar field....

Comment: I was focused on the "linear" part.

Comment: Indeed, nothing wrong with what you wrote, I was just adding to it.

Comment: @SeanLake In order to use these with the example I added, would I use integrals for the f and g?

Comment: No. The operator in this case is the maximum value of a function. If I scale a function by a multiple, does it's maximum scale by that same multiple? If I add two functions together, will the maximum of the added functions be the same as the sum of the maxima?

Comment: @SeanLake Thank you, I have a bad habit of forgetting maximal....like my brain doesn't even see the word.